# Running Javascript in an iframe from a different domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working on a website that uses iframes from another company to display a list of documents. The documents are paginated under a number of tabs ("All, Presentations, Reports", etc). If I use this  element as an example:

`<iframe id="frame" src="www.different-domain.com"></iframe>`

... is there a way I can open a specific tab, upon page load? So, if I want to open up a page with "Presentations" loaded, rather than "All" (the default), can I use Javascript/jQuery to accomplish this?

The tabs inside the  use Javascript to generate a list of all of the items, like this:

`<a href="javascript:loadPresentationData()">Presentations</a>`

I can't simply run this:

`document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.loadPresentationData();`

... as I will get 'Permission denied to access property 'loadPresentationData'.

If I open the iframe src in a new browser tab, go to the console, and type 'loadPresentationData();', it works perfectly, though!

Is there any other way I can just get the tab to open upon page load, without having to contact the developers of the frame (this was supposed to be finalised already).

If I did have to contact them, what would I need to ask them to do, so that I could open the tab upon page load?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can manipulate tabs in the iframe is IMHO through url.
It depends on how they (the 3rd party) implemented tabs. In [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) for example you can access the tab with hashes 
e.g.

```
www.differentdomain.com/#tab-3
```

Note that for further investigation, we'd need to know more details (the real domain for example)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could tell the document in the iframe to do stuff, and neither can be done unilaterally.

As @stove mentionned, the easiest way (for structural things like tabs) would be to use the URL with a hash; the app on the other domain just needs to support them.

The other, more flexible way would be to use [Cross-document messaging](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging) (you'll find a very relevant example there). For that to work, the developers of the app on the other domain must write a message handler on their side.